# Should I often create a class to indicate the type in python?

Tags: python

I have to learn Python now.

I feel it is really quite opposite to strongly typed language, such as OCaml and Java,  and the type thing is faded largely.

For example, when I read someone's code, I have no idea of what's the input and what's the output. Sometimes, it can be a list of dict whose value is a dict whose value is again a list.

What I have to do is to run it and print it then I know.

I haven't got used to this.

1. How to get used to this?
2. Should I create some classes just to indicate the type?
3. What's the general rules?

Comment: that's [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) for you.  the usual way is:  good docstrings for functions, descriptive variable names, and lots of unit tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to focus on what you want you code to do and don't worry about the types.  Is that a list?  Or is it some custom class that's wrapped around a list?  If you need to iterate over it then you actually don't need to know now.  You care about the contents not the details of the container.  So Python provides iteration which allows you to do something like:

```
for each in stuff:
    do_something(each)
```

Similarly if you want to see if something is `in` some container than you can use:

```
if something in stuff:
    do_something(stuff)
    # or perhaps in some other cases:
    something.some_method()
    # or
    stuff.do_it_with(something)
```

... and it doesn't matter whether stuff is a list, a set, a dictionary, a tuple, an SQL query result set, a DBM mapping (indexed file) etc.  Those are implementation details.

When you have an object you care whether it implements the semantics you're trying to call upon.  Whether that object *is* of a certain type ... or whether it's some sort of proxy or wrapper around some instance of that type ... or some alternative type offering the same functionality ... in Python all those are treated as irrelevant.  If it provides the methods (which promise the desired semantics) then call them.  If you need to handle the possibility that the object doesn't support the desired methods then wrap the call in an exception handler (`try:` ... `except ...`).

(I realize my code might look rather meaningless.  It's valid code; but your question is sufficiently abstract that it's hard to give a meaningful example.  The point I'm trying to make is that Python coding allows you to focus on semantics rather than the type/casting details).

Comment: I think the advantage described in your answer seems to be good to code writer, but not reader? I mean, e.g., for `stuff.do_it_with(something)` if I take your code and don't know what is stuff or something, only thing I can do is to try and if fail I find out why. Is this the paradigm?

Comment: When reading Python code you generally want to focus on the semantics being implemented rather than the types involved.  When trying to understand the code enough to make changes to it you do have to drill back to the class/type in order to survey any additional methods (and, as you say, return values).  The easiest way to do that, usually, is to fire up iPython (or just the Python interpreter) ... instantiate an object of the appropriate class, and use introspection to view it's methods and iPython's ? (help) magic or 'pydoc' and your browser to read through its docstrings.

Answer (score 1):

Comments, doc strings and doc tests go a very long way in helping you figure out what a function expects as input/ outputs. Python 3 also added type annotations, which aren't used for anything by the interpreter, but help the reader tremendously:

```
def find_key_max(d:dict):
    return max(d.keys())

def find_value_max(d:dict):
    return max(d.values())
```

Just by giving functions useful names and adding type annotations I've made it fairly clear what these functions do. A comment would have been even more helpful:

```
def find_key_max(d:dict):
    """Finds the largest key in the dictionary d"""
    return max(d.keys())
```

Of course, this only applies to cases where the type of the input argument really matters. The magic of Python is that often times the exact type doesn't matter. If I passed in a `list` instead of a dict in the method above, the error message will clearly say what the issue was. Such errors are very easy to catch with a simple smoke test.

Besides, many programmers (myself included) feel they don't need a compiler looking over their shoulder telling them if I can or cannot call `MyObject.my_method`. If I want to, I will, get out of my way, compiler! Trust me, I know what I'm doing. This philosophy let's you write code much faster, because you don't have to work to please a compiler. If something quacks like a duck (it has a `quack` method), then it is of type `Duck`. I don't care if the compiler thinks it is of type `Chicken`, it quacks and will therefore do the job.

Comment: That's a *docstring* - not a comment :)

Comment: Well, it is also a comment because it is not executable code. But I take you point :)

Comment: Well... comments don't get pass the parse stage, so aren't available to the bytecode while docstrings can be bound to the appropriate method and retrieved later for doc strings / docs tools etc... I'd say they're fairly distinct :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to know what type it is use the isinstance method

```
if isinstance(variable, int):
    # Do integer stuff here
```

Alternately if you want to force the input of a specific type.

```
def my_funciton(in):
    assert isinstance(in, int), "in is not an integer!"
```

I recommend you document everything as always.

```
def my_function(in):
    """calculate some result.

    Args:
        in (int): This is an integer input

    Return:
        (int): the input variable multiplied by 2
    """
    return in*2
# end my_function
```

There are many different ways to document the code in python. I suggest that you find something that is compatible with sphinx. There are several sphinx plugins available for different styles.